Cannot set compiler as g++-14 at CLion at macos. "Test Cmake run finished with error "
How to set the clion at macos correctly to make it use gcc-14?
I want my Clion in MacOS compile with the g++-14 instead of Clang. When I set up the toolchain, it did not pass the test. Clion gives "Test Cmake run finished with error". This is the screen shot

The error log can be checked, it is:
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-14
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-14 - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/bin/gcc-14"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment1/_build8067461596482658387/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ygVZwu'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/x64/ninja -v cmTC_479b5
    [1/2] /usr/local/bin/gcc-14    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_479b5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment1/_build8067461596482658387/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ygVZwu/testCCompiler.c
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_479b5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
    /usr/local/bin/gcc-14    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_479b5.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment1/_build8067461596482658387/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ygVZwu/testCCompiler.c
    clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-x86-pad-for-align=false'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'
    clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '--x86-slh-loads=false'?
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Error code: 1

It seems that the test was running with clang parameters. It was concerned that I have not installed the true gcc-14, it was just a alias of clang. So I outputed the version info of the gcc and gcc-14 at my mac(see below). According to this, gcc is an alias of clang, however, gcc-14 is not. I did install gcc-14 by homebrew. But how to make the clion run with the correct gcc-14 parameters?
(base) chenyangxu@Chenyangs-MacBook-Pro bin % which gcc         
/usr/bin/gcc
(base) chenyangxu@Chenyangs-MacBook-Pro bin % which gcc-14
/usr/local/bin/gcc-14

(base) chenyangxu@Chenyangs-MacBook-Pro bin % gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

(base) chenyangxu@Chenyangs-MacBook-Pro bin % gcc-14 --version
gcc-14 (Homebrew GCC 14.2.0) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


I am new to c++. I want to use gcc-14 at Clion because my homework is tested at linux and compiled by gcc-14. I want to develop it at my mac, thinking about making it consistent to the linux environment.
I had another post asking the same question: Issues with setting compiler as g++-11/14 at CLion at macos. "Test Cmake run finished with error ". That question was edited for too many times so I decided to write a new post here.

gcc-14 is also clang alias. It's weird that gcc-14 --version does not show that. I suggest that your remove it and use Apple clang.
